# Using JavaScript, Can I upload a word file and use .replace then save as new document

Tags: javascript, io, str-replace

Using JavaScript I would like to upload a word document and/or browse for file on local machine and view the contents... I would then like to replace the contents with different text.

Here is a snippet of the text replace I want to use.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Convert</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var str = document.getElementById("source").value; 

    var res = 
     str.replace(/a/g, "ა") 
        .replace(/b/g, "ბ") 
        .replace(/g/g, "გ") 
        //+ more letters for entire alphabet

document.getElementById("source").value=res;
}
</script>
```

What I would like to know is if it's possible to get the contents of a word document file, change all of the letters into Georgian characters (whilst retaining formatting if possible) then to save as a new word document?

Comment: I don't think there's a JS library that allows you to read and manipulate the contents of a file in proprietary M$ format…

Comment: Have you opened a Word document in a text editor (try Notepad or Notepad++)? You'll notice it's not just plain text...

Comment: You need a way to decode/uncompress it first. Can't you make a macro to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For docx you could use DOCX.js https://github.com/stephen-hardy/DOCX.js

Comment: This seems like a good solution and I am assuming since it converts to HTML that it will retain the documents formatting... am I correct?

Comment: Do you know of anywhere where documentation can be found?

Comment: Documentation about this lib is very poor. I'd recoment you try to reed code of this lib.

Comment: Yeah, so I see. Thanks for the help. This is clearly the correct method... implementing it will be the hard part.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a .docx file this should be possible since docx is XML. You might want to use the jQuery XML parser (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) or get the docs as XML string. With larger documents this might not be the best solution.

Comment: It will primarily be used for large documents so I think Shurok's answer may be closer to what I need.